# How to find related items based on a condition like minimum date in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a data model where we have projects and milestones. One project can have many milestones. I'd like to list each project and the milestone with the minimum date.

In the case of:

```
project1 -> milestone1 {date: '2019-01-01'}

project1 -> milestone2 {date: '2019-3-03'}

project2 -> milestone3 {date: '2018-01-01'}

project2 -> milestone4 {date: '2019-03-03'}
```

I want it to return

```
project1 -> milestone1 {date: '2019-01-01'}

project2 -> milestone3 {date: '2018-01-01'}
```

I've tried a bunch of crazy solutions where I calculate the minimum milestone dates, pass the min_dates using "with", then match again based on the calculated min date, but it seems wonky and is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

@user3137190, this is a succinct version of your answer:

```
MATCH (p:Project)-[:HAS_MILESTONE]->(m:Milestone)
WITH p, m ORDER BY p.name, m.date
RETURN p.name, COLLECT(m)[0].name
```

Comment: Thanks, that is much simpler

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in an unrelated post. I did not know we could use order by in a with clause

```
match (p:Project)-[:HAS_MILESTONE]-(m:Milestone)
with p, m order by p.name, m.date
with p, collect(m) as milestones
with p, milestones[0] as first_milestone
return p.name, first_milestone.name
```